# Log-off windows authentication IIS 8: using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iis, active-directory

I am using windows authentication feature in IIS to authenticate users im my php website. I could successfully log-in to my website and do my work.

But even if I close the tab or browser, the login information is cached inside the browser keep me logged in. What should I do to logoff from the website ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to add in the PHP source to force browsers not to cache;

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

[PHP Manual - Headers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you're following more common practices, then the login & other info are stored in $_SESSION.

Sounds like you'd want something like:

1. Create a php function that handles destroying a session.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php
2. On whatever event you choose, your function is called, destroying their session on the way out

A more appropriate approach is to basically set sessions to only last whilst the browser is open and to auto destroy on browser exist.  Same link above applies.

If you are using sessions, don't worry about headers directly - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php

Comment: I used the following code to clear the cache. Even if I cleared the cache manually, I am still logged-in<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo "You are logged out"; //Close the table in HTML?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I don't know a hell of a lot about this stuff.  But I believe that setting a cache header is about caching the content of the HTML, nothing to do with cookies/local data & whether or not your browser remembers that you are logged in (or not).  If your code uses sessions at all, I think you need to look into that - not header caching.